# c++ Aggregate initialization, what's under the hood?

Tags: c++, initialization, aggregate

*Aggregate initialization*   https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization
What is the underline mechanism when providing braces, all member gets initialized sequentially ?
Puzzled, there is no  constructor avaiable ...

```
struct A {

   int  var1 ;

   int  var2 ;
  };

  const A obj1={10,20};   // what's happening under the hood ? 

  const A obj2{10,20};
```

Comment: From the page you linked: *Each direct public base, (since C++17) array element, or non-static class member, in order of array subscript/appearance in the class definition, is copy-initialized from the corresponding clause of the initializer list.* In your case, `var1` is copy-initialized from 10 and `var2` is copy-initialized from 20.

Comment: [Possibly helpful reading](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.aggr) if you really want to get to the bottom of things. Well, at least as close to the bottom as the C++ Standard goes.

Comment: Many thanks for the response !  Just want to confirm , so compiler will do a this.var1 = init_value  when it see A obj1={10,20} ?

Comment: @iamxuxiao it will set `var1` to `10` and `var2` to `20`. You can not use assignment operator on a const object

Comment: The compiler just makes `obj1` have the value you want, by magic.  There's nothing special happening under the hood.  The standard says that, and it happens.